# Error in the App Bundle generation signature Gradle [8.0.1] and Java 17

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-console

I don't know if anyone else has experienced this but since upgrading to Android Studio Flamingo, along with Gradle 8.0 I'm having a lot of problems. One of them in the signed App Bundles.

I have an app published a long time ago in the Play Store (about a year and a half) today I was about to launch a new update, but when I uploaded it I found an error in the Play Console

[image]

In the image, the red text indicates: "The Android App Bundle has not been signed". And yes, I went to Android Studio, clicked on Build > Generate Signed App Bundle and went through the process selecting my keystore and all the information, along with the alias and password as I have always done. What's more, as you can see below, Android Studio notified me that it had been successful.

[image]

```
    kotlin { jvmToolchain(17) } // or kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
```

I have Java version 17 configured, but there is no way. On the other hand, I tried with the command ./gradlew bundleRelease and there I got an error.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:transformReleaseClassesWithAsm'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not create task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
      > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' property 'javaCompiler'.
         > No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=17, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}.
            > No locally installed toolchains match (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:auto_detection) and toolchain download repositories have not been configured (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/toolchains.html#sub:download_repositories).
```

I have tried many things but none of them work, does anyone know what is going on or what the solution might be?

Comment: I get this error message when using Flamingo - Generate Signed Bundle:

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil